# following error when starting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I'm starting eclipse got following error.
java 10 , jdk 1.8 eclipse_v1.7.0_79 tomcat 7.0 using

**

> !SESSION 2018-07-21 09:12:20.235
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700 java.version=10.0.1
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data D:\DEV\workspace_EDU !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-21 09:12:22.841 !MESSAGE Startup error !STACK 1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
>   of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450) Caused by:
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start()
>   of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
>     ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System
>   Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint:
>   Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     ... 12 more

**

Answer (score 0):

You've installed a version of the Eclipse IDE more than a couple of years older than your version of Java.Download the new version Of eclipse and try Again it will be done...

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/photon/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe        this link will direct you to download the latest version of eclipse